# Gradient Descent Overshooting and Cost Blowing Up when used for Regularized Logistic Regression

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression, gradient-descent, regularized

I'm using MATLAB to code **Regularized Logistic Regression** and am using **Gradient Descent** to discover the parameters. All is based on Andrew Ng's Coursera Machine Learning course. I am trying to code the cost function from Andrew's notes/videos. I am not entirely sure if I'm doing it right.

The main problem is... if the number of iterations gets too large, my cost seems to be **blowing up**. This happens regardless of whether I normalize or not (converting all the data to be between 0 and 1). This problem also causes the decision boundary being produced to shrink (underfit?). Below are **three** sample results that were obtained, where the decision boundaries of GD are compared against that of Matlab's `fminunc`.

[image: Regularized GD vs. fminunc, along with the cost history (30K iterations)] 
[image: Regularized GD vs. fminunc, along with the cost history (70K iterations)]
[image: Regularized GD vs. fminunc, along with the cost history (120K iterations)]

As can be seen, the cost shoots up when the number of iterations increases. Could it be that I incorrectly coded the cost? Or is there indeed a possibility that Gradient Descent can overshoot? If it helps, I am providing my code. The code I used to calculate the cost history is:
`costHistory(i) = (-1 * ( (1/m) * y'*log(h_x) + (1-y)'*log(1-h_x))) + ( (lambda/(2*m)) * sum(theta(2:end).^2) );`, based on the equation below:

[image: Regularized Cost Function for Logistic Regression]

The full code is given below. Note that I have called other functions as well in this code. Would appreciate any pointers! :) Thank you in advance!

```
% REGULARIZED Logistic Regression with Gradient Descent
clc; clear all; close all;
dataset = load('ex2data2.txt');
x = dataset(:,1:end-1); y = dataset(:,end); m = length(y);

% Mapping the features (includes adding the intercept term)
x = mapFeature(x(:,1), x(:,2)); % Change to polynomial of the 6th degree

% Define the initial thetas. Same as the number of features, including
% the newly added intercept term (1s)
theta = zeros(size(x,2),1) + 0.05;
initial_theta = theta; % will be used later...

% Set lambda equals to 1
lambda = 1;
% calculate theta transpose x and also the hypothesis h_x
alpha = 0.005;
itr = 120000; % number of iterations set to 120K
for i = 1:itr
    ttrx = x * theta; % theta transpose x
    h_x = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-ttrx)); % sigmoid hypothesis
    error = h_x - y;
    % the gradient a.k.a. the derivative of J(\theta)
    for j = 1:length(theta)
        if j == 1
            gradientA(j,1) = 1/m * (error)' * x(:,j);
            theta(j) =  theta(j) - alpha * gradientA(j,1);
        else
            gradientA(j,1) = (1/m * (error)' * x(:,j)) - (lambda/m)*theta(j);
            theta(j) =  theta(j) - alpha * gradientA(j,1);
        end
    end

    costHistory(i) = (-1 * ( (1/m) * y'*log(h_x) + (1-y)'*log(1-h_x))) + ( (lambda/(2*m)) * sum(theta(2:end).^2) );
end

[cost, grad] = costFunctionReg(initial_theta, x, y, lambda);
%  Using MATLAB's built-in function fminunc to minimze the cost function
%  Set options for fminunc
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 500);
%  Run fminunc to obtain the optimal theta
%  This function will return theta and the cost
[thetafm, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunctionReg(t, x, y, lambda)), initial_theta, options);

close all;
plotDecisionBoundary_git(theta, x, y); % based on GD
plotDecisionBoundary_git(thetafm, x, y); % based on fminunc

figure;
plot(1:itr, costHistory(:), '--r');
title('The cost history based on GD');
```

Comment: You got wrong on computing `costHistory`. You multiplied `1/m` only by `y'*log(h_x)` and not also by `(1-y)'*log(1-h_x)`. The correct compute is: `costHistory(i) = (-1 * ( (1/m) *( y'*log(h_x) + (1-y)'*log(1-h_x)))) + ( (lambda/(2*m)) * sum(theta(2:end).^2) );`

Comment: Also on the gradient of `theta_j` for `j>1`, you need to **add** the regularization (not to subtract). Instead of `gradientA(j,1) = (1/m * (error)' * x(:,j)) - (lambda/m)*theta(j);` you should write `gradientA(j,1) = (1/m * (error)' * x(:,j)) + (lambda/m)*theta(j);`